# Playing sound using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have created a simple app that has few buttons in a screen. one of the button is called a soundButton, where, when the user press it, an audio file will be played. (e.g. a simple word like "apple"). i have around 100 of those similar screens, and when i play the sound for the first few times, i can hear the sound, and after a while, i can no longer hear them no matter which screen i go to (even the previous screen which can be heard no longer plays the sound)
this is my coding, for reference :

```
package com.example.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class EngApple extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eng_apple);

        ImageButton soundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound);
        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.apple);


        soundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mp1.start();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must call MediaPlayer method **release()** in  **onPause()** or **onStop()** in Activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()

Comment: but my app is something like a flash card style. basically an image of an item is shown on the screen and when the user press the soundButton, the word pronunciation will be played. example in this case, a picture of apple, and when pressed the button, the word "apple" will play. the sound clip is only 2seconds long at most, do i still need to do the onPause() or onStop() method?